# JavaFX:How to slide a pane properly when stage with shadow effect?

Tags: javafx, slide, shadow, stage

I have seen this question on "[JavaFX: how to create slide in animation effect for a pane (inside a transparent stage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601900/javafx-how-to-create-slide-in-animation-effect-for-a-pane-inside-a-transparent/59508279#59508279)".

And I don't understand that partial code on the last comment posted by John Astralidis. It seems to solve my problem. I would like to slide a pane with a shadow stage. Now my problem is the slide animation play out of my visual root pane bound, it just play with stage (or actual root pane) bound.

My visual root pane is a child of actual root pane, I set the actual root pane with padding and Corlor.TRANSPARENT to implement my visual root pane shadow effect.

[image: slide image]

here is the code I had modified from John Astralidis and Felipe Guizar Diaz.
the start code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);//
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

the FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="anchorPane" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="500" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;"   
        fx:controller="leftslidemenusample.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
    <ToolBar AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" minHeight="56.0"   >
           <Button text="menu" fx:id="menu"  />
    </ToolBar>
    <StackPane fx:id="mainContent"  style="-fx-background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.30)" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="56.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"    >
        <children>
        </children>
    </StackPane>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="navList" style="-fx-background-color:white" AnchorPane.topAnchor="56.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" prefWidth="180.0" translateX="-180"   >
        <children>
            <Label text="left side menu"/>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

and the controller FXMLDocumentController.java

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;
@FXML
private Button menu;
@FXML
private AnchorPane navList;

private double shadowSize = 15;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(500,500);

    anchorPane.setClip(rectangle);
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(setupShadowPane());

    prepareSlideMenuAnimation();
}
private Pane setupShadowPane() {
    Pane shadowPane = new Pane();
    shadowPane.setPrefHeight(500);
    shadowPane.setPrefWidth(500);
    shadowPane.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: RED;" +
                    "-fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, black, " + 20 + ", 0, 0, 0);" +
                    "-fx-background-insets: " + shadowSize + ";"
    );

    Rectangle innerBounds = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle outerBounds = new Rectangle();
    shadowPane.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
        System.out.println(newBounds.getWidth());
        innerBounds.relocate(newBounds.getMinX() + shadowSize, newBounds.getMinY() + shadowSize);
        innerBounds.setWidth(newBounds.getWidth() - shadowSize * 2);
        innerBounds.setHeight(newBounds.getHeight() - shadowSize * 2);
        outerBounds.setWidth(newBounds.getWidth());
        outerBounds.setHeight(newBounds.getHeight());

        Shape clip = Shape.subtract(outerBounds, innerBounds);
        shadowPane.setClip(clip);
    });

    return shadowPane;
}
private void prepareSlideMenuAnimation() {
    TranslateTransition openNav=new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), navList);
    openNav.setToX(0);
    TranslateTransition closeNav=new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), navList);
    menu.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt)->{
        if(navList.getTranslateX()!=0){
            openNav.play();
        }else{
            closeNav.setToX(-(navList.getWidth()));
            closeNav.play();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I get it done.I think John Astralidis's answer is wrong.But thanks.The keys are:

1. Use a StackPane as a actual root pane,then add visual root pane and shadow pane to actual root pane as StackPane's children.Visual root pane is the need to add shadow effect pane.
2. Set visual root pane with chip that corps its outer layout to show shadow pane's shadow effect;
3. Set shadow pane with chip that corps its inner layout to show visual root pane's content.

Wishing my answer with my bad English can help somebody.I post my entire demo code below:

**The starter class--FXApplication.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class FXApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);//
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**The layout FXML file--FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="pane" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="500" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;"
        fx:controller="FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="500" style="-fx-background-color: WHITE;">
        <children>
            <ToolBar AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" minHeight="56.0"   >
                <Button text="menu" fx:id="menu"  />
            </ToolBar>
            <StackPane fx:id="mainContent"  style="-fx-background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.30)" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="56.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"    >
                <children>
                </children>
            </StackPane>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="navList" style="-fx-background-color:white" AnchorPane.topAnchor="56.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" prefWidth="180.0" translateX="-180"   >
                <children>
                    <Label text="left side menu"/>
                </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</children>
```

The controller class--FXMLDocumentController.java

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;
@FXML
private StackPane pane;
@FXML
private Button menu;
@FXML
private AnchorPane navList;
private double shadowSize = 10;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(480,480);
    rectangle.relocate(10,10);
    anchorPane.setClip(rectangle);
    pane.getChildren().add(setupShadowPane());

    prepareSlideMenuAnimation();
}
private Pane setupShadowPane() {
    Pane shadowPane = new Pane();
    shadowPane.setPrefHeight(500);
    shadowPane.setPrefWidth(500);
    shadowPane.setStyle(
            "-fx-background-color: RED;" +
                    "-fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, black, " + 20 + ", 0, 0, 0);" +
                    "-fx-background-insets: " + shadowSize + ";"
    );

    Rectangle innerBounds = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle outerBounds = new Rectangle();
    shadowPane.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
        innerBounds.relocate(newBounds.getMinX() + shadowSize, newBounds.getMinY() + shadowSize);
        innerBounds.setWidth(newBounds.getWidth() - shadowSize * 2);
        innerBounds.setHeight(newBounds.getHeight() - shadowSize * 2);
        outerBounds.setWidth(newBounds.getWidth());
        outerBounds.setHeight(newBounds.getHeight());

        Shape clip = Shape.subtract(outerBounds, innerBounds);
        shadowPane.setClip(clip);
    });

    return shadowPane;
}
private void prepareSlideMenuAnimation() {
    TranslateTransition openNav=new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), navList);
    openNav.setToX(0 + shadowSize);
    TranslateTransition closeNav=new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), navList);
    menu.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt)->{
        if(navList.getTranslateX()!=0+shadowSize){
            openNav.play();
        }else{
            closeNav.setToX(-(navList.getWidth())+shadowSize);
            closeNav.play();
        }
    });
}
```

}

And the image below:

[image]

[image]